# Create new instance of a Thread everytime I want to run it or not

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a class that implements runnable something like :

```
private class myThread implements Runnable {
    @overide
    Public void run(){
    //refreshes a page
    }
}
```

Now lets say I have a button that I want to run the thread when pressed so in the onClick I will have :

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(new myThread());
myThread.start();
```

Now my question is should I do create an instance of that class everytime I click the button or should it just be done once when the application runs then onClick I only do

```
myThread.start();
```

If so could that cause any problems if someone decided to repeatadly press the refresh button before the thread has time to finish ? 
What would be the pros and cons of creating a new instance everytime ?

I am doing this in Android so I would like to know how that could affect anything the app is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no choice here. You can only call `start()` once for each instance of a `Thread`; it will throw an `IllegalThreadStateException` if you call `start()` a second time for the same `Thread` object. Make a new instance for each click.

However, if the `MyThread` class doesn't maintain any internal instance data, you don't need a new instance of `MyThread` each time. You can create a single `MyThread` object and reuse it each time you create a new `Thread`:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(mMyThread);
```

(where `mMyThread` is an instance stored in a member field and created once).

In my view, the cleanest approach is to subclass `Thread` instead of implementing `Runnable`:

```
private class MyThread extends Thread {
    @overide
    Public void run(){
        //refreshes a page
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
new MyThread().start();
```

and don't have to worry about whether or not the `MyThread` class has instance data that needs to be private to each `Thread` instance. (It would have the added benefit of making the name faithful to the actual object type.)

Comment: Hmm I see , but what if I check if the previous thread is done before i start() the thread again onClick ,would it be beneficial in any way to not have to create a new instance everytime ?

Comment: @Amroelaswar - You **cannot** start the thread again. The system won't let you do it. As I pointed out in my edit, you probably don't need a new instance of `MyThread` each time, but you do need a new `Thread` object each time. (By the way, I'd rename the class `MyRunnable` instead of `MyThread`, since it's not a `Thread` subclass.)

Comment: ok thanks for that will accept answer , and I know but just got used to calling it thread, helps me put things together ehen coding ;)